# SQL Query Help Required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I Have folowing query to get data of Previous 45 days

```
SELECT evening + morning + calve_milk AS Total_Today, 
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(6), m_date, 6) AS Date 
FROM Status 
WHERE (m_date < (SELECT MAX(m_date) AS Expr1 FROM Status AS Status_2))
   AND (m_date > (SELECT MAX(m_date) AS Expr1 FROM Status AS Status_1) - 45) 
   AND (animal_code = @animal_code) 
GROUP BY evening + morning + calve_milk, m_date 
ORDER BY m_date
```

When the data is retrieved with then the date column is look like this

```
Jan 01
Jan 02
Jan 03
Jan 04
ans so on till the jan ends
Feb 01
Feb 02
Feb 03
```

My Question is that is this possible to skip the repeting JAN and FEB with each date and date should be look like this

```
Jan 01
    02
    03
    04
Feb 01
    02
    03
```

Please any one tell me how can i do this using sql

Comment: Any one Please answer to the question

Comment: Look to improve your accept ratio - accept the best answers of the questions you've asked previously, otherwise people will be hesitatnt to help you.

Comment: This seems more like a question about how to display the information. Why do you want to do it in SQL?

Comment: I want to skip the the repeating word JAN till month changes

Answer (score 6):

Possible, sure, sensible, probably not.

You should be getting your data with your SQL and formatting the data in a front end application (e.g. Reporting Services, Excel etc.).

Comment: No I have to format it on asp.net chrt x-axis is there any method to format it on chart then tell me that method

Comment: That method would be better explained as an answer to a question relating to ASP.Net Chart Date Axis formatting, not this T-SQL question!

Comment: @user1103342 Still, probably better to format it in the data binding than in the SQL. If you'd want the same data displayed slightly differently in another chart, you'd end up having to write/test/optimize more SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. It's an example with another table. It creates everything. You can just run it and look how it works:

```
DROP TABLE CURSOR_EXAMPLE
GO
CREATE TABLE CURSOR_EXAMPLE
(TEXT VARCHAR(8),VALUE BIGINT)
GO
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Jan',1)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Jan',2)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Feb',1)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Feb',2)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Mar',1)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Mar',2)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Apr',1)
INSERT INTO CURSOR_EXAMPLE
VALUES ('Apr',2)
GO

DECLARE @var_Current_TEXT VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @value BIGINT;

CREATE TABLE #TempResult
(TEXT VARCHAR(8),VALUE BIGINT)


DECLARE cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE CURSOR FOR  
SELECT 
    TEXT
    ,VALUE
FROM CURSOR_EXAMPLE

OPEN cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE  
FETCH NEXT FROM cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE INTO @text, @value 

SET @var_Current_TEXT = ''
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    IF (@var_Current_TEXT <> @text)
        INSERT INTO #TempResult
        VALUES (@text, @value); 
    IF  (@var_Current_TEXT = @text)
        INSERT INTO #TempResult
        VALUES ('', @value); 

   SET @var_Current_TEXT = @text
   FETCH NEXT FROM cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE INTO @text, @value
END 
CLOSE cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE  
DEALLOCATE cu_CURSOR_EXAMPLE

SELECT * FROM  #TempResult

DROP TABLE #TempResult
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE AS (
select mnth
,stats
,row_number() over(partition by mnth order by mnth) rn
from you_Table
)
select case when rn>1 THEN '' Else mnth END, stats
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Fixed up your SQL so it's parsing ok. CTE:s are declared `CTE AS (`.